# Making 3D model from pictures - writing the stereo matching part

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-3d, photogrammetry

I did not took computer vision in college but I'd like to give it a try.
I want to make 3D model from a set of pictures.

I know you can do it with 123d catch or agisoft photoscan. doing it is not the point, it's writing the software.

At first I want to do stereo image matching then reconstruction from those 2 image, then multi view image matching and reconstruction.

According to this :
http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/eval/
The best algorythm is TSGO.

However I can't find any information about this TSGO algoritm, would any of you would know what TSGO stand for?

or if you know a better one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The link on the page refers to a yet-to-be published paper:

> [143] Anonymous. Accurate stereo matching by two step global
>   optimization. ECCV 2014 submission 74.

You'll have to wait until [ECCV 2014 (September 6-12, 2014)](http://eccv2014.org/) to read it.

Meanwhile, you can take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org). It implements several stereo algorithms and get help you get up and running with the setup. Once you write your own implementation, you can contribute it to the community via OpenCV.

Answer (score 1):

The paper and code is available at

http://www.cvc.uab.es/~mozerov/Stereo/index.htm

But it is not the best now...

Comment: It might be helpful if you suggest what algorithm is the state of the art now.